# Building a Termite Farm

Tags: containment, terrariums, insects, farm-animals

So me and my friend have decided to make a termite farm and with me and him both being in high school, we don't really know the best materials for it. We have looked it up and have only found a small one on [kenneth-noll.uconn.edu](https://kenneth-noll.uconn.edu/how-to-build-a-termite-farm/), but it isn't big enough and will result in a possible outbreak. However, we came up of the smart yet possibly collapsible idea of turning a fish aquarium into a full fledged termite farm. Please tell me if this could result in a disaster.

Comment: I have found a termite nest in my uncles yard about a year ago and i dont know what kind they are, my plan is to look for the queen, get some others, and just nuke the rest of the nest.

Comment: Welcome to Pets.SE! Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. This is not a general discussion forum, but a Q&A site, which means that each post should only contain a single question. Could you please [edit] your question and concentrate on a single question? You can open a second post for your second question.

Comment: Thank you @Elmy and certainly i will edit my question. I did not realise it was a Q&A site. My mistake. Have a nice day and Have a wonderful Easter.

Comment: How are the things with building your termite farm? Please note that SE network permits and even encourages answering your own questions. Quite a few people voted for your question (including me) and I think all of us are curious and would be interested in the solution. If you succeeded at building something remarkable and useful that makes a nice home for the termites, then please consider summarizing it in an answer to your own question - your written description of how have you built that and how have you solved the problems presented in your question would be valuable...

Comment: ... and really helpful for anyone who wants to build something similar in the future and finds this Q&A; especially if you include a few photos of the finished enclosure, too. Nobody has answered this question so far because, I assume, we have no one who is experienced with termites; however, if you have built it nonetheless and it works, then it is now **you** who is experienced; and the answer from someone experienced would definitely be appreciated by Pets SE users and most possibly rewarded with reputation; thanks.

Comment: Yes, We have figured out that with a mason jar, petroleum jelly, a 1  MM drill but, and drill, and some boxing tape can make a pretty decent small farm.

Comment: However we havent really gotten the materials yet, we are pretty confident that it will work

Comment: This german website [antnet](https://www.antstore.net/forum/termiten-fur-anfanger-t3075.html) states, that the kind of termites who are possible pets are not visible (living inside of wood), others interesting to observe build nests too big for a one family home and also close every gap light would come into the nest, so not observable. The third kind even is able to cut through plastics and thin metal, like jar lids. And nobody want to have wood eating animals in the furniture ;) So I would assume the enclosure is much more elaborate than a jar ;) if even possible to build one

Answer (score 0):

So I am doing pretty good, I have a theory that  I think will work. If you want to build a decent termite farm, Then here are your materials.

A Power Drill

A 1 millimetre drill bit

A mason jar with a metal lid and seal

Clear Boxing Tape

Cardboard

Mulch/Rotting Wood

Dirt/Soil

And last but absolutely not least, Your favorite Termites.

You might want to put enough food in the jar so the termites have enough to eat for a long time.

If you want to make a huge interconnected farm, Then buy alot of jars and one big one. The big one will be "The Feeding Chamber". You will be using tubing to connect the jars to the big jar.

Then connect the The Feeding Chamber" to other areas using tubing.

Comment: The 1 MM bit is for air and ventilation holes. due to methane build up from decomposing plants, you will need ventilation or your termites will de.

Answer (score 0):

Subterranean termites are pretty easy to contain. They are unfortunately common in E TX. They build a soil tunnel from the wood/food to the ground, so if you break up any tunnels they will tend to remain in the container. I inadvertently built one; Concrete planter about 18" cube, open on top. I put in a lot of broken twigs and leaves from the yard, then covered with native and potting soils. A few months later , when planting bulbs, I found I had made a termite condo. Because it is on a concrete patio it would be easy to see any tunnels and I could see escapees. So, my experience is they would stay in an aquarium even without a top.