# New enviroment introduction for termites

Tags: introducing-pets, stress, insects, new-pets, invertebrates

How would I introduce termites that I capture to their new environment ([a farm that I am building](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/31031)) without causing too much stress to them?

Comment: I also came up with the idea of turning a mason jar into a termite farm by drilling tiny holes into the lid big enough to let air in, but small enough keep the termites in. Its a temporary farm because i have heard that termites reproduce very rapidly.